# How to get ticker from yahoo finance and use for TkInter and enable Entry widget in OOP

Tags: tkinter, yahoo-finance, ticker

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from scipy.stats import norm

from pandas_datareader import data as wb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
% matplotlib inline

from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials

from yahoo_fin import stock_info as si

from decimal import Decimal

import math


class Searcpages:

    def __init__(self, master):
        master.title('Searcpage'
        self.entry_stock = ttk.Entry(self.frame_content, width=30, font=('Arial', 15))
        self.entry_stock.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=15, columnspan=2)

        ttk.Button(self.frame_content, text='OK', command=self.ok).grid(row=6, column=0, padx=5, sticky='e')
        ttk.Button(self.frame_content, text='Clear', command=self.clear).grid(row=6, column=1, padx=5, sticky='w')

    def ok(self):
        tickers = [self.entry_stock]

        yahoo_financials = YahooFinancials(tickers)

        new_data = pd.DataFrame()
        for t in tickers: new_data[t] = wb.DataReader(t, data_source='yahoo', start='2004-1-1')['Adj Close']

        print(new_data[t])

        self.clear()

    def clear(self):
        self.entry_stock.delete(0, 'end')


def main():
    root = Tk()
    searchpage = Searcpages(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

It shows me the following problem:

> File "", line 73, in ok
>       yahoo_financials = YahooFinancials(tickers)   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/yahoofinancials/**init**.py",
>   line 78, in **init**
>       self.ticker = ticker.upper() if isinstance(ticker, str) else [t.upper() for t in ticker]   File
>   "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/yahoofinancials/**init**.py",
>   line 78, in 
>       self.ticker = ticker.upper() if isinstance(ticker, str) else [t.upper() for t in ticker]
>
> 'Entry' object has no attribute 'upper'

Then I found the following OOP yahoofinancials code that is what the error says , however I do not know where to put to make my Tkinter code to incorporate through ticker the data from yahoo finance. Please help:

```
def __init__(self, ticker):

    self.ticker = ticker.upper() if isinstance(ticker, str) else [t.upper() for t in ticker]
    self._cache = {}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to call `upper()` on an `Entry` object which is why you get the error.

To get the content of the `Entry`, use `Entry.get()`:

```
tickers = [self.entry_stock.get()]
```